# Get pagetitle in wordpress with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

for my google event tracking, I need to have the Page Title in Wordpress of the current site within a jquery function.

There are many ways to get the title with php, but I´m not really shure, that it is the best way.

Thank you, Cheers Marten

Comment: You can easily do this with JavaScript using the code var title = $(document).find("title").text();

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you generate this page title, you need to pass this through to your JS script.

You can do this with `wp_localize_script()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

So after you have enqueued the script you can then pass parameters through.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'script_vars', array('site_title' => 'This is my site title' );
```

You can then use it in your JS file like this:

```
alert(script_vars.site_title);
```

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
alert(document.title);
```

depending on your setting you want to strip out the blog name out of it

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to get the title in PHP:

```
$title = get_the_title();
```

Include your javascript file:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', '../source/to/your/javascript_file.js' )
```

Then you need to send the $title variable to your javascript file using wp_localize_script():

```
wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'script_vars', array('site_title' => $title );
```

Now you have access to the site_title in your javascript file by doing so:

```
var site_title = script_vars.site_title;
console.log(site_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
$(document).find("title").text();
```

**javascript**

```
document.title
```

or

```
var sPath=window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(sPage);
```

Comment: sorry I´ve forgotten to write, that I need the wordpress post title and not the meta-title. Sorry for that!